# When to use private/protected methods in Typescript with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, access-modifiers

I am currently working on a **React** application with Typescript. When a component should provide a functionality with a ref a usually use a **public** method (`public focus() : void {...}`), but I cannot decide when a component's method should be **private** and when **protected**.

I know that private and protected members are both accessible from the transpiled code, so the accessibility is basically the same during execution. So rather my question is: **as best practice (wrt. a React component), which methods should be marked as private/protected and why**(event handlers, custom handlers, component logic, etc.)?

Answer (score 13):

This depends on developer's preferences.

All members that are supposed to be publicly available (including lifecycle hooks) can be made `public`, e.g. a method that was designed to be called externally with React ref. The rest can be made `protected` or `private`, according to [the principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). This applies to any class, not just React. The choice may depend on whether a class is used internally or published as a part of the library, internal classes can be easily refactored according to current needs while overzealous encapsulation in a library will deprive a user of methods that a user could benefit in public API.

The use of `private` prevents the class from being effectively extended. This may not a big problem in React because it promotes [composition over inheritance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

A choice between `private` and `protected` is a matter of taste, basically a choice between meticulous encapsulation and preemptive extensibility. The use of `protected` can be more justified because it provides practical benefits while drawbacks are rare.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so well.